# Saving instance in one activity and displaying in different activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to hitting back button after rotating the screen. I'm aware that on screen rotation, the activity What am trying to do is

1. **Type message in 1st activity**
2. **Display message in 2nd activity**
3. **Rotating screen and saving "ata" through onSaveInstanceState()**
4. **Recreating 2nd activity**
5. **Hitting back button on 2nd activity (recreating 1st activity - onCreate() called)**

Since savedInstanceState was not null, it should display whatever saved. Bu alas, null is being displayed. Here's the code

1st Activity :-

```
package dummy.pack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CommonHandler{

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "dummy.MESSAGE";
public static String DISPLAY_MESSAGE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    **if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        DISPLAY_MESSAGE = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
        DISPLAY_MESSAGE = DISPLAY_MESSAGE + " calling from create";
        getMessage();
    }**
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    System.gc();
}

**public void getMessage() {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(DISPLAY_MESSAGE);
    setContentView(textView);
}**

@Override
public void onRestart (){
    super.onRestart();
    DISPLAY_MESSAGE = "Normal 1";
    getMessage();
}

}
```

2nd Activity :-

```
package dummy.pack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity implements CommonHandler{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the message from Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
**public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveState) {
    saveState.putString("message","Recreate");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveState);
}**
}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: i guess you need to obverride the onSaveInstanceState method of MainActivity activity as well

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your activity in manifest file

```
<activity android:name="Activity name"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|">
```

and this in your activity

```
 if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

    Log.e("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");
}else{

    Log.e("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");
}
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".

Comment: I only need to know whether saving Bundle from one activity is visible from another activity when recreated?